# React objects in list are reset on re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-hooks

I am currently working on a react website. It has a parent component with the stateful variable playing:

```
const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(songData[0] !== "none");
```

This is passed down to this list-component (the details are not important here):

```
function Songs(){
    return(
        songs.map(i=>{
            return(
                <MaxOneSong key={i.Name} Colors={Colors} audio={audio} name={i.Name} current={i.Name == playingSong} description={i.Description} playing={playing} setPlaying={setPlaying} playSong={()=>{
                    playSong(i.Name, `./audio/${i.File}.mp3`);
                }}/>
            );
        })
    );
}
```

Here's the problem. The stateful variables in my "MaxRunningSong" component are reset to their initial value (defined in the useState() call) whenever playing updates. This only occurs to these listed components, not to other children. How can I fix this?

While trying to fix this, I added states the the normal children components, showing me that the problem does in fact only occur in the listed components.

EDIT:

Here's the code of the song component. I intentionally set the inital value of width to 15 to be sure the problem is caused by a state reset (because of an unmount). This code shouldn't be important, since the timebar movement specified in this code works, it's just reset once when toggling "playing" and then goes right back to the right amount when the 1s interval is called again.

```
export default function MaxOneSong({Colors, audio, current, name, description, playing, setPlaying, playSong}) {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(15);

    const mouseOver = useRef(false);

    const timeBarRef = useRef();
    const timeBarContainerRef = useRef();

    useEffect(()=>{
        //If mouse moves, move timebar
        //TimebarContainer = 50vw, width: %

        timeBarContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
            if(audio && current){
                const ww = window.innerWidth;
                if(e.clientX >= 0.23*ww && e.clientX <= 0.77*ww){
                    setWidth((e.clientX/ww-0.23)/0.0054);
                }
            }else{
                setWidth(0);
            }
        });
        timeBarContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{
            mouseOver.current = true;
        });
        return () => {
            if(timeBarContainerRef.current){
                timeBarContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("mousemove", (e)=>{
                    if(audio && current){
                        const ww = window.innerWidth;
                        if(e.clientX >= 0.23*ww && e.clientX <= 0.77*ww){
                            setWidth((e.clientX/ww-0.23)/0.0054);
                        }
                    }else{
                        setWidth(0);
                    }
                });
                timeBarContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("mouseover", (e)=>{
                    mouseOver.current = true;
                });
            }
        }
    }, []);


    useEffect(()=>{
        //Auto timebar moves

        if(audio && current){
            const intervalID = window.setInterval(() => {
                if(!mouseOver.current) {
                    if(audio.ended){
                        setWidth(100);
                        setPlaying(false);
                    }else{
                        setWidth(100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration);
                    }
                }
            }, 1000);
            timeBarContainerRef.current.addEventListener("mouseleave", (e)=>{
                mouseOver.current = false;
                if(audio.ended){
                    setWidth(100);
                }else{
                    setWidth(100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration);
                }
            });

            //Set time
            timeBarContainerRef.current.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
                if(mouseOver.current) {
                    const ww = window.innerWidth;
                    audio.currentTime = audio.duration * ((e.clientX/ww-0.23)/0.54);
                }
            });

            return ()=>{
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                if(timeBarContainerRef.current){
                    timeBarContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("mouseleave", (e)=>{
                        mouseOver.current = false;
                        if(audio) {
                            if(audio.ended){
                                setWidth(100);
                            }else{
                                setWidth(100 * audio.currentTime / audio.duration);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    timeBarContainerRef.current.removeEventListener("click", (e)=>{
                        if(audio && mouseOver.current) {
                            const ww = window.innerWidth;
                            audio.currentTime = audio.duration * ((e.clientX/ww-0.23)/0.54);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }, [audio]);


    const boxStyle = {
        outline: "0.3vmin solid",
        borderRadius: "2vw",
        width: "50vw",
        padding: "1vh 2vw 1vh 2vw",
        fontSize: "3vmin",
        position: "relative",
        zIndex: "1",
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .1)",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        justifyContent: "space-between",
        cursor: "pointer",
        overflow: "hidden",
        height: current ? "4.5vh" : "4vh"
    }

    const timeBarStyle = {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "0",
        backgroundColor: "red",
        width: `${width}%`
    }

    const timeBarContainerStyle = {
        position: "absolute",
        left: "0",
        top: "88%",
        width: "100%",
        height: "12%"
    }
    
    return (
        <div style={boxStyle} onClick={()=>{
            if(current){
                setPlaying(!playing);
            }else{
                playSong();
            }
        }}>
            <div style={{fontWeight:"bold"}}>{name}</div>
            <div>{description}</div>
            <div style={timeBarContainerStyle} ref={timeBarContainerRef} className="timebarContainer">
                <div style={timeBarStyle} ref={timeBarRef} className="timebar">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: First off, `songs !== []` will always return true. Are you meaning to check if `songs` is empty?

Comment: As for your state resetting, you are conditionally rendering the children so they are unmounted and remounted based on that condition and as such reinitialize state on each remount. You're also using an incrementing `key` value which will tell react that it is a new component every time it is rendered, instead use a unique property of the mapped object such as `song.id` or possibly `song.name`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @pilchard! I changed the code in the function to this:
|View in Edit|
Unfortunately, the components still unmount when "playing" updates. Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: You're passing a method `playSong` - when is it called? Additionally, it would be interesting to see where you state is actually set.

Comment: @NotX Hey there, playSong is called whenever the user selects a song that is not already selected. It doesn't really have anything to do with the problem.
As for the second part of your question, I'm not sure which state you mean. The "playing" state that resets the components is toggled by clicking on the song that is currently selected. The state in the children that is being reset gets updated once every second (timebar for the song). When "playing" is toggled, the timebar goes to the initial value insantly and then back to the correct time when the interval is called again. Code in edit.

Comment: Phew, my guess is that `MaxOneSong` causes a re-mounting. Hard to tell b/c Idk who for example `audio` works and everything's rather messy. You could add a log and see whether `setPlaying(false);` is triggered at a wrong time at least. I'ld recommend to strip the `MaxOneSong` to a minimum and see whether the faulty behavior remains. If it disappears, introduce complexity step by step-

Comment: That said, all your `useEffect` dependencies are wrong and will be called at the wrong times: `audio` is not a primitive and additionally not listed in all `useEffect()` dependencies where it is used, `current` is not listed in any `useEffect()` dependency at all. In fact, you're depending on `[audio != null, current]` in the first `useEffect` call and on `[audio.currentTime, audio.ended, audio.currentTime, audio != null, current]` in the second `useEffect()` call - and I probaby missed some more. Also, make sure all these values are primitives!

Comment: @NotX thanks, I copied most of the code from a different component I made before so I should have looked into those things more. That being said, I‘m pretty sure it‘s not the cause of my problem though. I made a little test project in which I could recreate the same problem in two very simple components. I‘ll ask a new question based on that later today so it‘s hopefully going to be easier to understand.